# Desktop Comupter with Ubuntu built in

Tags: helpfile

Are their any major manufacturers in the USA who have Desktop (not laptop or notebook) but old fashioned Desktop computers that come built with Ubuntu as it's operating system right out of the box instead of windows?

I don't want to repartition or do anything with a windows system, I just want to change to something that has Ubuntu as it's native operating system built in and I want it to be a Desktop with room to add memory, expansion bays, card readers...etc.....

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not sure this is a shopping recommendation. A shopping recommendation asks "Which element of S should I pick?" This asks, "Is there any element of S?" This question could be answered by providing information about where to find lists of computers that ship with Ubuntu that include some desktop computers. I believe Canonical maintains such a list; an answer specifying it would not become obsolete as new products and technologies come into existence, so the point of prohibiting shopping recommendations would not apply.

Comment: To close voters.  I believe this is a valid question its not asking which computer should I buy (the answer to which is both subjective and would soon be out of date) but do pre-installed Ubuntu desktops exist.  The answer is yes and my answer to this question provides links from the official Ubuntu community web site.

Comment: "Is there someone that sells systems with Ubuntu?" that's what this question is cut through the bone, and that's a by the book shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several companies providing Computers both laptops and desktops with Ubuntu pre-installed.

My answer would be off-topic if I were to make any personal recommendation but there is a list of companies together with links to companies maintained  in the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)

Specifically here: [UbuntuPre-installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed)